# How to add "add to favorite" button or icon in detail, that will be add in "favorite" page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a GirdView with some elements, each element have it's own detail page, i want to add a button or an icon in detail to save them in "favorite" Page locally and permanently, so the user can find them in later use.
is there any documentation or a tutorial about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store something locally, you can try use shared_preferences [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). It's pretty straight to use it example :

```
_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

For more information here's [medium guide](https://medium.com/@suragch/saving-and-reading-data-in-flutter-with-sharedpreferences-bb4238d3105)